# How to make the java wait for x seconds and then execute

Tags: java, android, xml

I making an app and I would run in to a problem that I can't fix.
I am using Android Studio and I need to make a Button that I have already made. Do more then it already does. I want it to after display a text also close the app. Do you know how I should program that. It would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Here is the Java code:

```
package test.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Button button=(Button) v;
    ((Button) v).setText("Correct");
}


public void buttonAnClick(View q) {
    Button button=(Button) q;
    ((Button) q).setText("Niet goed");
}
```

}

So I have already made the button in XML and told it:

android:onClick="buttonOnClick"

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Your title and body don't match. You should be more clear and descriptive in your body. Also, you don't need to do all that in the onClick to change the text of the View which you already have a reference to.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000);` Will make a program pause for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
     Button button=(Button) v;
     ((Button) v).setText("Correct");
     new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             finish();
         }
     },1000); // milliseconds: 1 seg.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to have something happen afterwards what you're looking for is this:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //What you want to happen later
            }
        }, 1500); //1500 = 1.5 seconds, time in milli before it happens.
```

Put that in your button's method.

If you want to close your app you should call

```
      finish();
```

Finish closes out the current activity. If you have other activities on the stack you'd return to them but since you likely only have 1 it should take you out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pause then use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`.

For example:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get something done with a delay when a button is pressed then do it something like this:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Button button=(Button) v;
    button.setText("Correct");
    button.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
       public void run() {
           //runs after 1 second delay on UI thread
       }
    }, 1000L);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put method into your button click function

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
      //call method here
}
```

If you want to use RxJava

```
Disposable di = Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .subscribe(timer->{
        //next action after 2 seconds
   },throwable->{
       // throw exception 
   });
```

To destroy disposable use, `di.dispose();`

if Use Runnable and Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         //next action after 2 seconds
    }
}, 2*1000);
```

to stop the handler use, `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`